# Find the number of starting stations that visits all petrol pumps in a circular tour

Tags: python

Suppose there is a circle. There are n petrol pumps on that circle. You are given two sets of data.
The amount of petrol that every petrol pump has.
Distance from that petrol pump to the next petrol pump.
Calculate the first point from where a truck will be able to complete the circle (The truck will stop at each petrol pump and it has infinite capacity).  Assume for 1-litre petrol, the truck can go 1 unit of distance.

I know how to solve this using a queue in O(n), but I wanted to know if we can find the total number of possible starting stations that complete the circular tour in O(n) time.

```
class PetrolPump: 
      
    def __init__(self,petrol, distance): 
        self.petrol = petrol 
        self.distance = distance  
def printTour(arr): 
      
    n = len(arr) 
    # Consider first petrol pump as starting point 
    start = 0 
    end = 1 
      
    curr_petrol = arr[start].petrol - arr[start].distance  
        # Run a loop whie all petrol pumps are not visited 
    # And we have reached first petrol pump again with 0  
    # or more petrol 
    while(end != start or curr_petrol < 0 ): 
          
        # If current amount of petrol pumps are not visited 
        # And we have reached first petrol pump again with 
        # 0 or more petrol  
        while(curr_petrol < 0 and start != end): 
              
            # Remove starting petrol pump. Change start 
            curr_petrol -= arr[start].petrol - arr[start].distance 
            start = (start +1)%n 
              
            # If 0 is being considered as start again, then 
            # there is no possible solution 
            if start == 0: 
                return -1
  
        # Add a petrol pump to current tour 
        curr_petrol += arr[end].petrol - arr[end].distance  
          
        end = (end +1) % n 
  
    return start
```

This is my sol for the original question.

I am a beginner pls help me and I will be very grateful

Comment: Doing homework is fun but you need to make an attempt. Also, python and java? Pick one. What do you specifically need help with?

Comment: Basically python

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for your problem. Happy to see that you are beginner and trying to solve this problem, I hope this code helps you.

```
class PetrolPump: 
      

    def __init__(self,petrol, distance): 
        self.petrol = petrol 
        self.distance = distance  
def printTour(arr): 
      
    n = len(arr) 
    start = 0 
    end = 1 
      
    curr_petrol = arr[start].petrol - arr[start].distance  
      
    while(end != start or curr_petrol < 0 ): 
      
        while(curr_petrol < 0 and start != end): 
              
            # Remove starting petrol pump. Change start 
            curr_petrol -= arr[start].petrol - arr[start].distance 
            start = (start +1)%n 
  
            if start == 0: 
                return -1
  
        # Add a petrol pump to current tour 
        curr_petrol += arr[end].petrol - arr[end].distance  
          
        end = (end +1) % n 
  
    return start  
  
# Driver program to test above function 
arr = [PetrolPump(6,4), PetrolPump(3,6), PetrolPump(7,3)] 
start = printTour(arr) 
  
print "No solution" if start == -1 else "start =", start
```

Comment: I also did the same for the original problem but I wanted to know if we can find the total number of stations in O(n) time .  This sol I think will only give us the first station and not the total number of stations . Thanks for your help

Comment: What did you change/add, and why does that solve the problem? An answer should explain itself, not just dump code.